# How to read errors when compiling from source code

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ffmpeg, compilation

**Goal**:

Compile multiple libraries from source code to ultimately install a fully compiled version of FFmpeg with desirable libraries attached.

**Problem**:

During the compilation, all libraries (seemingly) are successful until liblv2 is reached.

**Error output via terminal**:

```
building lv2 - version 1.18.10
=======================
Downloading https://lv2plug.in/spec/lv2-1.18.10.tar.xz as lv2-1.18.10.tar.bz2
... Done
Extracted lv2-1.18.10.tar.bz2
$ python3 ./waf configure --prefix=/home/jman/tmp/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-build/workspace --lv2-user
python3: can't open file '/home/jman/tmp/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-build/packages/lv2-1.18.10/./waf': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Failed to Execute python3 ./waf configure --prefix=/home/jman/tmp/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-build/workspace --lv2-user
```

**Where I need guidance**:

```
python3: can't open file '/home/jman/tmp/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-build/packages/lv2-1.18.10/./waf': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

**My question**:

What does this part mean?

```
lv2-1.18.10/./waf'

specifically the part /./
```

**My best guess so far is it**:

1. obviously is looking for a directory it can't find (perhaps because it truly doesn't exist)
2. The missing `'waf'` directory should be located inside either the `"${PACKAGES}"` or `"${WORKSPACE}"` directory.

The `${PACKAGES}"` path in this script should = `/home/jman/tmp/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-build/packages`

The `${WORKSPACE}"` path in this script should = `/home/jman/tmp/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-build/workspace`

**The full build script**:

`https://github.com/slyfox1186/ffmpeg-build-script/blob/master/scripts/build-ffmpeg`

I tried my best to make this worth sometimes time without giving too much info... sorry if I don't meet the expectations of this forum.

Am I even close?

Comment: `.` is a name that points to its containing directory. So `/.` can be ignored. `foo/./bar` is the same as `foo/bar`

Comment: It happened because you wrote `python ./waf` instead of just `python waf`.

Comment: so i was missing an entire line of code and apparently, that code skipped over the part that was giving me an error and then continued the build with other libraries that are working now. I changed the python3 ./waf to python3 waf as recommended. Thanks for the help and explanations Barmar.